# liquibaseGenerateChangelog changeSets count 0 when trying to create initial change log from JPA classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I have a Gradle based project, containing a number of JPA entity classes.

I do not have a database yet, but I would like to generate the collection of liquibase `changesets` in XML.

So I can then populate an empty database with an initial schema definition.

The problem is using the `liquibaseGenerateChangelog` Gradle task, even though I provide the package containing the classes, the resulting XML `changeset` file doesn't contain any `changesets`

Command to generate change log from my JPA entities:

```
./gradlew liquibaseGenerateChangelog
--changeLogFile=src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml
--url=hibernate:spring:com.company.project.domain?dialect=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateGenericDialect
--driver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver
```

Empty file that liquibase creates:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.1.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd"/>
```

I have classes inside `com.company.project.domain` e.g:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
  private Long id;

  // etc
```

I have the following inside `build.gradle`:

```
..
implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core"
implementation "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
liquibaseRuntime "org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:4.6.1"
liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different sample databases included with Liquibase. Since you don't have a database to test against, you can try using one of those to test your configuration. Here is a link with details about running the included H2 database, and another to our course about using the Liquibase Test Harness.

https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/init/start-h2.html?Highlight=h2
https://learn.liquibase.com/catalog/info/id:130